# Multi-processor cache coherence

Tags: performance, caching, cpu-cache

I struggle to understand what cache coherence guarantees x86 cpus really give me.

In particular, I'm wondering what happens when multiple threads read and modify the same location very rapidly - as they would when I'm serving a million requests per second with a web server that just reads the total amount of requests that it has served so far (for example).

Obviously this would have to be at least either of

- slow
- incorrect

Am I right? Which one?

Comment: Maybe [this post] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) explains the situation?

Comment: Maybe, but not obviously so.